# Older version app downloads Android play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

I have uploaded new version of app on the play store and unpublished the older version in console two weeks ago. But the "daily installs by device" data on the play store console shows that the older version is still downloaded.

How is that possible, if the older version is unpublished?

Comment: It is possible that you've changed some properties like minSdk, which makes that for some devices, the older version is the only version compatible for those devices.

Comment: No, minSdk is same.

Answer (score 2):

The statistics you see are correct. The numbers against older versions are for those users who have not updated your app yet, and are still using the older version. Over time, as users update the app, you will see the count against the latest version increasing and those against older versions decreasing.

Also, the new version may take some time to replicates over all servers. So it is possible that you can see a few downloads of the older version for a few days till the new version is pushed to all servers.

Comment: Its daily installs by device not current installs. So it does not matter if user updates the app or not. It only shows the fresh downloads.

Comment: Its been more than 2 weeks and if google is not able to update all the servers with new app, then i don't know who can .

Comment: did you choose staged rollout?

Comment: No, Full rollout.